# Watermarks not working anymore, the cache has been cleared

Tags: magento, caching, magento-1.7

I'm having the strangest issue with watermarks in Magento recently. Yesterday I updated the opacity and it got extremely dark (the watermark) for about 30 minutes, then the website crashed and now watermarks aren't working at all..

I have cleared the image cache and every other cache, I have changed from PNG-24 to PNG-8 and also tried JPEG and still the water marks aren't working at all. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2